# Change image without reloading the page based on current language JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, swap, lang

I try to change an Image (first slide of the carousel) based on the current language without reloading the page, using JQuery. So far I have become with this, but for some reason is dot not work. (I am a beginner)

> HTML Code sample

```
<picture>
    <source  id="premierSlide" srcset="assets/img/header/BG1.png" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
    <source srcset="assets/img/mobile/BG1-tablet.png" media="(min-width: 768px)">
    <source srcset="assets/img/mobile/BG1.png" media="(min-width: 320px)">
    <img    srcset="assets/img/header/BG1.png" alt="responsive image" class="d-block img-fluid">
</picture>
```

> JQUERY code sample

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($'html').attr('currentLang') != 'FR' ) {
        $('#premierSlide').attr('srcset', 'assets/img/header/BG1.png')
    }else{
        $('#premierSlide').attr('srcset', 'assets/img/header/BG1ENG.png')
    }
});
```

Any help will be great appreciated!

Comment: Please be more precise on "dot not work", does it produce errors in console? what does it do that you didn't expect?

Comment: #1 does not work*, sorry.

Comment: Update: it does not swap the image based on the current language, the language function is working fine, i verified with console.log, but the image does not change using the code above. Not even after page reload, in fact it does work but only with a page refresh using the following  function slideLang(currentLang) {
        var firstSlide;
        if(currentLang!="FR"){
         document.getElementById('premierSlide').srcset="assets/img/header/BG1ENG.png"
        }else{
          document.getElementById('premierSlide').srcset="assets/img/header/BG1.png"
        }
      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the typo:

```
 if ($'html').attr('currentLang') != 'FR' ) {
```

to

```
 if ($('html').attr('currentLang') != 'FR' ) {
```

Comment: Was one of the problem (ups, but thank you!), but it does not work though. Nothing is happening, not even after refresh.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function slideLang(currentLang) {
    var firstSlide;
    if(currentLang!="FR"){
     document.getElementById('premierSlide').srcset="assets/img/header/BG1ENG.png"
    }else{
      document.getElementById('premierSlide').srcset="assets/img/header/BG1.png"
    }
  }
```

Update: It's working using this method.